# Remote desktop solution for teaching

Tags: untagged

My problem,

I'm going to teach a group of 15 students over a video conference system (all setup and working), Students are located in several different places even different countries. +1 if the software is Free/Open Source Software.

What I need is:

1. The students need to see my desktop (OSX), students run Ubuntu (8.X/9.X)
2. We are two teachers and need to switch between our desktops without disconnecting
   connected students. (OSX and Ubuntu)
3. Teachers need to connect and view students screens (one at a time).

I know about [VNCReflector](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vnc-reflector/) which will solve 1,2 but not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just run VNCReflector for switching all students between the teaching machines, and regular VNC server on the student machines so that the teacher can connect back. 1, 2, 3, done.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate the *-edu distributions. They commonly have solutions for such problems. Althoug if you use (the same) Linux on the teachers machines it would probably be a lot easier since the integration would be already there.

Is there a specific reason/requirement for the teachers to run OSX. I guess it's probably because teachers don't want to get used to a new desktop but demand that from their pupils.

Comment: Regarding Ubuntu vs OSX you are correct and it gives the question some dimension :) But if we find a good solution for say Ubuntu only that is probably good enough.. (I'll _make_ him use Ubuntu ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.netsupportmanager.com/ (netsupport manager /School) NetSupport Manager provides the ability to support Windows, Mac, Linux, Solaris and mobile devices all from a single console. only thing is that is eval/trail for 15/30 days.